# url working fine in browser but returning null in android using async task

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch an `ip address` from a `URL`, it returns `NULL` in android but the url is working fine in the browser

Code so far:

```
class ipaddress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;

    String ipaddress;

    public ipaddress(Context ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String web_url = "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(web_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String verification_data = URLEncoder.encode("format", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("json", "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(verification_data);

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();


            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bfreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,  "iso-8859-1"));

            String result = "";

            String line = "";


            while ((line = bfreader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }

            bfreader.close();

            inputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

calling the method:

```
 ipaddress ip = new ipaddress(getActivity());

 ip.execute();
```

I am getting an accurate result when I open the `URL` in my broswer, but when I accessing the `URL` on android using this code, it returns `NULL`

Kindly please let me know what mistake I've made.

Comment: This site ("Use HttpsUrlConnection to fetch data
" - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting) may have some related details.

Comment: Try this. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`    `String line;`   `while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {sb.append(line+"\n");}`  and then `String result = sb.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an enough reputation to comment so instead decided to use answer. Unless you learning so as to familiarize yourself with Java and Android I suggest you use a library such as OkHttp by Square. It makes your work far much easier.